# iOS: How can I disable autorotate in iOS 8.3.? none of the solutions I found online works

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-orientation

I'm trying to enforce portrait view of my app on iOS. It should be a simple thing but none of the solutions I found online seem to work. Here is the segment of code in my view controller:

```
- ( void )viewWillAppear:( BOOL )animated
{
    [ super viewWillAppear:animated ];

    [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] setValue:@( 1 ) forKey:@"orientation" ];
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
//  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;   //tried both
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

It's an union of several solutions / posts I found online, and my app still "rotates like a charm". Is there something obvious that I'm missing? I'm developing on Xcode 6.3 for iOS 8.3.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding the code from the answer to this question to the navigation controller's delegate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645626/how-to-disable-autorotation-in-ios-8-for-a-particular-controller?rq=1

Comment: @BSPM thanks for the comment, I found that the mistake I made is having added the shouldAutoRotate function to the view controller instead of the navigation controller. Adding it to the navigation controller solved the problem. Now however the keyboard and the status bar on the top still rotates, is there anyway to disable that? I found a solution here but it doesn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941849/disable-orientation-for-keyboard-in-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enforce portrait orientation across your entire app just set supported interface orientations on your "Deployment info" section of the project's "General" target settings, here: [image]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want! (knew there should be something as simple as this.) hope I have more reputation to upvote