# How can I maintain the proportional position of a view after a rotation?

Tags: ios, uiview, camera, rotation, position

What's the secret behind apps like Apple's Camera app, which can maintain the position of a view on the physical screen between rotations? I mean like when you rotate the Camera app, and the icons keep their position albeit spinning accordingly. (Messenger does this too when taking a picture for instance)

I've tried Auto Layout, setting the frame, viewWillTrasitionToSize(_:withTransitionCoordinator:), viewWillLayoutSubviews(), everything; but nothing seems to get the job done.

Even when invalidating the constraints and making new ones, or when resetting the frame, it still leaves its position for a moment before adopting the new coordinates.

So, does anyone how they do it? Or at least a way to replicate it?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this article is helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645626/how-to-disable-autorotation-in-ios-8-for-a-particular-controller

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I'm looking for, I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to that of Apple's Camera app:(

Comment: You will need to avoid  autorotation of the view, but detect that the device was rotated and than rotate only the icons/buttons clockwise or ccw with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation.

Comment: @iCode Makes complete sense! Will try it and let you know

Comment: @iCode Thanks! It may not be what Apple does but as far as I'm concerned it works just fine and Facebook appears to do the same